# what is (+) syntax in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know what the (+) in the below query signify,

```
select ..
from ..., Fat fat
where prop = fat.prop (+)
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you research? (Google/Bing/MySql Book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the obsolete outer join symbol.

In Oracle, **(+)** denotes the "optional" table in the JOIN.

You may check out this for **[Left and Right Outer Joins](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/LeftandRightOuterJoins.htm)**.

**On a side note:-**(Although its obsolete)

The placement of the (+) determines RIGHT or LEFT. If the **(+)** is on the right, it's a **LEFT JOIN** and if **(+)** is on the left, it's a **RIGHT JOIN**.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle specifically, indicates a Left Outer Join. Older notation.

Answer (score 0):

Out of date format of outer join.  Means only matching rows on the `(+)` sign side and all rows on the other side.  You should use the `LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN` notation instead.